# Hide a Div til x no of characters in inputx box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am using this javascript to count characters in input box.

what i want to do is, i want to display this DIV (countdown) only when the characters reaches 5 in input box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't told us which div you want to show/hide, so just replace the `#divToShow` selector with the proper one for the div:

```
$(".message").keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val().length >= 5) {
        $("#divToShow").show();
    } else {
        $("#divToShow").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i would use method 'change', because we need to hide our div when length of text less then 5 characters